# "This Vienna Red, an almost extinct style, is our contribution to Lager."

Tags: grammatical-number

I (non-native English speaker) wrote this sentence as one part of a beer description. It feels right to me. Some people started insisting that *Lager* should actually be *Lagers*.

What I mean to say is *a contribution to the style "Lager"*.

Are both version correct or only one of them? Please explain why.

Comment: *lager* can be construed as a *count noun*, in which case *lagers* is the correct plural, but also as a *mass noun*, in which case *lager* is the correct plural. Both are correct, but in my opinion, the mass noun *lager* sounds better than *lagers*.

Comment: To those people who don't like your version, ask them to substitute in "beers", which sounds funny: "This Vienna Red is out contribution to beer**s**". "This Vienna Red is our contribution to beer" sounds much better.

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lager for the mass/count noun lager.

Comment: Both 'the world of lager' and 'the world of lagers' are used, but the former vastly predominates on the internet. As one would expect, this does not define a pattern. 'The world of men' outperforms 'the world of man'.

Comment: Note the inconsistency of 'He drinks wine' vs 'He drinks spirits'.

Comment: As you are contributing a style of lager to a world of multiple styles of lager, I agree with the 'some people'. 'Lagers' would be better.

Comment: It sounds fine to me, just the way it is.  You could instead say "Lagers", but that just says you're adding one more to the vast array of such brews, where "Lager" implies that you're improving the art.

Answer (score 1):

> Lager - A kind of effervescent beer which is light in colour and body

The contribution is to a *kind* of beer, not to *kinds* of beer. Therefore you seek the singular 'lager'.

That lager can be a count noun or a mass noun (http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lager) is in this case irrelevant.

Comment: Suppose a company manufactures a new type of pen. They could say "This is our contribution to pens." Here, 'pens' is both plural and is functioning as a kind term (what is called an *artifactual kind*). I don't think kind terms are always singular, which is suggested by your explanation.

Comment: @Silenus "This is our contribution to the pen." (If you invented the Bic.) Any problem sits with the word 'contribution', not 'lager'. Because Vienna Red doesn't add to the type (not all lager has Vienna Red in it), but adds to the breadth of the type.

Comment: But "the world of men" is more common according to Google data than "the world of man"; I'd say neither is significantly different in meaning from "the human world".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth 'men' in 'the world of men' is very often intended to be plural masculine. It is about worlds or scenes dominated by men; not man. Think: darts. Look it up on the regular Google. It has little to do with 'the human world'. But I don't know whether the analogy would be proper in the first place.

Comment: The question is whether the plural forms of various nouns (here, lager) may be used in a non-count as well as the usual count way. With 'I wanted to get into conglomerates', it is obvious that 'conglomerates'' _is_ used that way (*'I wanted to get into some / several / three conglomerates'). As with Silenus's example  "This is our contribution to pens." These may well be deletions from 'the field of ...' /  'the world of ...' / etc, but cannot be treated as standard count usages. Here, 'lager' as the singular-form mass noun is the usual choice, but the plural-form mass noun is not incorrect.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't think 'conglomerate' is similar to 'lager', and therefore I don't think the analogy is valid. However, I would be interested in learning about your "deletions" concept. Reference?

Comment: "He's in plastics / munitions / arms ..." are further examples of plural-form non-count usages. (I'm with CaGEL in adopting the definition of a non-count noun usage as one where a numeral may not be inserted.) Note that the first example is far more commonly used than "He's in plastic", probably for the obvious reason. Also, 'He drinks spirits' vs He drinks wine'. // Look up 'deletions' here; John Lawler gives a lot of material.

Comment: With 'He drinks wine' you seem to shoot yourself in the foot as 'he drinks wines' seems very weird. How is 'wine' linguistically different from 'lager'? (I'm going to look up the "deletions" stuff. Thanks.)

Comment: Since I'm saying that plural-form non-count nouns [with, possibly, isoformal count-noun true plurals, as in two lagers, three pens] are [sometimes] available rather than mandatory, the only foot shot here is not mine.

Comment: @Keepthesemind - if a bar stocks 15 varieties of lager, could you not say "they stock 15 lagers"?